# Trying to make JTextField uneditable

Tags: java, jtextfield

Problem: I am trying to make my JTextField uneditable in both of these panels. In the east panel. And also I have a button that says Roll the dice since it is a board game im trying to make, and it generates random numbers from 0 to 6. But when i get the number i can still edit the text. For the user name it is still editable after i ask the user through JOptionPane in the beginning of the program to enter their username before they play the game, then i did a setText method so it sets their name in the box. While the program is still running, i can still edit their name..

Comment: I don't see any code that uses the setEditable? You can just use throwField2.setEditable(false);

Comment: `throwField2.setEditable(false);`

Answer (score 3):

you should use [setEditable(false)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setEditable(boolean)) method, it will do the job

Comment: ok guys thanks! i fixed it by just adding the throwField2 but I forgot the username panel had a nameField JTextField variable and i just did a nameField.setEditable(false) . Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

If you call `throwField2.setEditable(false)`, the user will no longer be able to edit the TextField